# twitter users with more than 1 million followers

Tags: python, api, twitter

How to find the twitter IDs of twitter users with more than 1 million followers? I am using python.
I tried using the streaming API of twitter and put a filter on tweets where the users had more than 1 million followers. But my efforts were in vein as I can never find those users whose live tweets I am not able to access.

Please help me keeping in mind the various bottlenecks of rate limit exceeded. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Twitter api doesn't provide that kind of functionality. Short answer: you can't.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want some Twitter users with more than 1 million followers, check out the list of verified IDs on Twitter here: https://twitter.com/verified/following.

You can easily retrieve this list and check the number of followers for each of the users.